# Multisesión con PHP

Tags: php, mysql

que tal? tengo una web donde utilizo un login, para acceder a un index.php contiene info para un lugar. El tema que ahora tengo que hacer otra misma web, pero con otra info de otro lugar. Y quiero utilizar el mismo login que ya tengo hecho, pero que segun usuario, vaya a la web que le corresponde. Estuve investigando, ya que soy nuevo en PHP, pero no le encuentro la forma, sin romper mi login. Si puediera pedir una ayuda de como armarlo..

Este es mi login:

```
<form action="autenticar.php" method="post">
                <img id="img-login" src="..\NQN-3623\Estilos\YPF-logo.jpg">
                <h1 class="titulo-login">LOGIN</h1>
                <div class="login-form">
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <input type="text" name="el_usuario" class="login-field" value="" placeholder="username"
                            maxlength="12" id="login-name" required>
                        <label class="login-field-icon fui-user" for="login-name"></label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <input type="password" name="la_clave" class="login-field" value="" placeholder="password"
                        maxlength="10" id="login-pass" required>
                    <label class="login-field-icon fui-lock" for="login-pass"></label>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-large btn-block" value="INICIAR SESION">
            </form>
```

y lo autentico con autenticar.php

```
<?php
  session_start();
  require_once("conectar.php");

  if ( !isset($_POST['el_usuario'], $_POST['la_clave']) )
{exit('Llenar todos los campos!');}

if ($stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT ID, clave FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = ?')){
$stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['el_usuario']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();

if ($stmt->num_rows > 0){
$stmt->bind_result($id, $clave);
$stmt->fetch();    

if(password_verify( $_POST['la_clave'],$clave)){
session_regenerate_id();
$_SESSION['loggedin'] = TRUE;
$_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['el_usuario'];
$_SESSION['ID'] = $id;
header('Location: ..\index.php');}

$stmt->close();}?>
```

tengo un ELSE por si pifia la contraseña o usuario, acorte para que no sea tan largo.
En la BD tengo la tabla 'usuarios' y con ID, username, password

Agradeceré cualquier sugerencia de cómo realizarlo.

gracias .-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

el login con session_start() guarda la sesión del usuario en la base de datos.
podrias hacer una tabla temporal donde se guarde un token del usuario y con ese dato generar el nuevo session_start() en el nuevo sitio si no esta logueado alli, puedes usar un tabla para verificar la sesion,el tiempo, y el dominio, así si la persona no refresca la hora se manda a logout.

tambien puedes usar coockies de sesion entre dominios
https://www.eslomas.com/2012/02/compartir-la-sesion-de-php-entre-subdominios/